# Mysql Join query with count table records with same date

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hello i am having two different table with same field `created_date` (datetime)
now i want records which counts daywise records with joining table i have done for individual counting as below query :

```
SELECT DATE(created_date), COUNT(*) FROM table1 GROUP BY DAY(created_date)
SELECT DATE(created_date), COUNT(*) FROM table2 GROUP BY DAY(created_date)
```

and i am getting results for individuals something like this:

[image]

[image]

RESULT I NEED :

```
DATE(created_date)      count(table1)       count(table2)
2016-12-01                  10                  3
2016-12-02                  1                   0
2016-12-05                  1                   0
2016-11-29                  1                   0
2016-11-30                  4                   1
```

Now i just want to join these result WITH INDIVIDUAL VIEW COUNT ACCORDING TO TABLE can anyone please help me out with this profile....

Comment: Please show us your original data.  Create a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Vipul, either data or desired output can be different, in second table last created date should '2016-11-30' or first table's last '2016-12-30'. But to get output as you have provided the date should be corrected in second table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First take a `UNION` between your two tables, then use conditional aggregation to determine the counts for each of the two tables.  Note that I introduce a field called `table_name` to keep track of data from each of the two tables.

```
SELECT t.created_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'one' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_table_one,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'two' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_table_two
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE(created_date) AS created_date, 'one' AS table_name
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE(created_date), 'two'
    FROM table2
) t
GROUP BY t.created_date
```

I used `DATE` consistently everywhere to make the query correct.

Comment: @VipulLakhtariya Please try my query again.  I think the issue is that your original counts were ignoring `NULL` (the default behavior).  I have added logic to preserve this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your queries, you are grouping by DAY(date) and showing 'date' so the result will be first date with day(date), yet repeating it to avoid misunderstanding :)

```
select IFNULL(A.cd, B.cd), A.cnt, B.cnt from 
 (SELECT DAY(created_date) d, DATE(created_date) cd, COUNT(*) cnt 
   FROM   table1 GROUP BY DAY(created_date)) as A
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT DAY(created_date) d, DATE(created_date) cd , COUNT(*) cnt 
    FROM table2 GROUP BY DAY(created_date)) B ON B.d = A.d
```

Comment: @Vipul, have you read comment to the code? what do you mean by "not exact"

Comment: @VipulLakhtariya Please show us your original data, thanks.

Comment: @Vipul, updated answer, but your screenshot only increase unknowness or what is "not exact" for your, at least now it should be similar to your answers "RESULT I NEED")

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
SELECT created_date, sum(countTable1) countTable1, 
    sum(countTable2) countTable2
FROM (
SELECT DATE(created_date) created_date, COUNT(*) countTable1, NULL countTable2 
FROM table1 GROUP BY DAY(created_date)
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(created_date) created_date, NULL, COUNT(*) countTable2 
FROM table2 GROUP BY DAY(created_date)) t GROUP BY t.created_date
```

Comment: This answer looks a lot like mine.

Answer (score 0):

Its not too hard just use `union` if no need to allow duplicate row else use `union all` for all(means allow duplicate as well).

```
SELECT DATE(created_date), COUNT(*) FROM table1 GROUP BY DAY(created_date)
UNION
SELECT DATE(created_date), COUNT(*) FROM table2 GROUP BY DAY(created_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.create_date,ISNULL(T.count,0)AS Counttable1,ISNULL(X.count,0)AS Counttable2 FROM(SELECT DATE(created_date) AS create_date,COUNT(*) as count FROM table1 GROUP BY DAY(created_date)) AS T LEFTJOIN(SELECT DATE(created_date) AS create_date, COUNT(*) as count FROM table2 GROUP BY DAY(created_date))AS X ON T.create_date=X.create_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need a SQL UNION.  JOIN natuarually eliminate counts becuase the maytch fields.  I.e. if you had 2016-12-01 in both `table1` and`table2` then a `JOIN` on `created_date` would give you a count of 1 instead of a count of 2.

```sql
SELECT DATE(total.created_date), COUNT(*)
FROM (
   SELECT created_date FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT created_date FROM table2) as total
GROUP BY total.created_date
```

HERE you simply union the two tables since they have a matching column name.  Then you get back every date from both tables.  That is in the inner query.  The outer query then does the counting.

Hope that makes sense.